# DIV positioning with position:relative

Tags: css

I have a page layout, where I have to set the position of a div relative and top:-30px
The DIV is positioned relative and top:-30 exactely.

But the following DIV then 30px distance at the top. Is there a way to fix this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make it position:absolute; and its parent position:relative;

This should work :)

Answer (score 7):

`position: relative` doesn't do what I think you think it does. It means that absolutely positioned elements within it are positioned relative to the relative div and not to the page. For example:

```
<div id="header">Header</div>
<div id="content">
  <div id="c1">Content One</div>
  <div id="c2">Content Two</div>
</div>
```

with

```
#header { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; height: 150px; width: 100%; }
#content { position: relative; margin-top: 150px; height: 500px; }
#c1 { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; }
#c2 { position: absolute; top: -50px; left: 0; }
```

`c1` will be at the top of the lower div, not the top of the page. `content` will be 150 pixels from the top of the page. `c2` will be above it due to the negative top. `header` will be at the top of the page.